# Tensorflow : ValueError Duplicate feature column key found for column

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, python-3.4, deep-learning

I was trying to get my hands dirty with Tensorflow and following 
[Wide and Deep Learning](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py) example code. I modified certain imports for it to work with python 3.4 on centos 7.

Highlights of the changes are:

```
    -import urllib
    +import urllib.request
```

...

```
    -urllib.urlretrieve
    +urllib.request.urlretrieve
```

...

On running the code, I am getting following error

```
    Training data is downloaded to /tmp/tmpw06u4_xl
    Test data is downloaded to /tmp/tmpjliqxhwh
    model directory = /tmp/tmpcyll7kck
    WARNING:tensorflow:Setting feature info to {'education': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.string, shape=None, is_sparse=True), 'capital_gain': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.int64, shape=TensorShape([Dimension(32561)]), is_sparse=False), 'capital_loss': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.int64, shape=TensorShape([Dimension(32561)]), is_sparse=False), 'hours_per_week': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.int64, shape=TensorShape([Dimension(32561)]), is_sparse=False), 'gender': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.string, shape=None, is_sparse=True), 'occupation': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.string, shape=None, is_sparse=True), 'native_country': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.string, shape=None, is_sparse=True), 'race': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.string, shape=None, is_sparse=True), 'age': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.int64, shape=TensorShape([Dimension(32561)]), is_sparse=False), 'education_num': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.int64, shape=TensorShape([Dimension(32561)]), is_sparse=False), 'marital_status': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.string, shape=None, is_sparse=True), 'workclass': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.string, shape=None, is_sparse=True), 'relationship': TensorSignature(dtype=tf.string, shape=None, is_sparse=True)}
    WARNING:tensorflow:Setting targets info to TensorSignature(dtype=tf.int64, shape=TensorShape([Dimension(32561)]), is_sparse=False)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "wide_n_deep_tutorial.py", line 213, in <module>
        tf.app.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
        sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
      File "wide_n_deep_tutorial.py", line 209, in main
        train_and_eval()
      File "wide_n_deep_tutorial.py", line 202, in train_and_eval
        m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=FLAGS.train_steps)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 240, in fit
        max_steps=max_steps)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 550, in _train_model
        train_op, loss_op = self._get_train_ops(features, targets)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 182, in _get_train_ops
        logits = self._logits(features, is_training=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 260, in _logits
        dnn_feature_columns = self._get_dnn_feature_columns()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 224, in _get_dnn_feature_columns
        feature_column_ops.check_feature_columns(self._dnn_feature_columns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py", line 318, in check_feature_columns
        f.name))
    ValueError: Duplicate feature column key found for column: education_embedding. This usually means that the column is almost identical to another column, and one must be discarded.
```

Is that I have change some variable or is this a python 3 problem. How can I get going forward with this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

**Final update** I had this problem with the recommended 0.10rc0 branch, but after reinstalling using the master (no branch on git clone) this problem went away.  I checked the source code and they fixed it.  Python 3 now gets the same results as Python 2 for wide_n_deep mode, after fixing the urllib.request thing you already mentioned.

For anyone coming later and still using 0.10rc0 branch, feel free to read on:

Had the same problem, and did some debugging.  Looks like a bug in tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py in the _EmbeddingColumn class.  The key(self) property is plagued by this bug:
https://bugs.python.org/issue24931

So instead of coming out with a nice unique key, we get the following key for all _EmbeddingColumn instances:
'_EmbeddingColumn()'

This causes the feature_column_ops.py's check_feature_columns() function to determine that the second _EmbeddingColumn instance is a duplicate since they keys of all of them are the same.

I'm kind of a Python noob, and I can't figure out how to monkey patch a property.  So I fixed this problem by creating a subclass at the top of the wide_n_deep tutorial file:

```
# EmbeddingColumn for Python 3.4 has a problem with key property
# can't monkey patch a property, so subclass it and make a method to create the 
# subclass to use instead of "embedding_column"
from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers.feature_column import _EmbeddingColumn
class _MonkeyEmbeddingColumn(_EmbeddingColumn):
  # override the key property
  @property
  def key(self):
    return "{}".format(self)

def monkey_embedding_column(sparse_id_column,
                     dimension,
                     combiner="mean",
                     initializer=None,
                     ckpt_to_load_from=None,
                     tensor_name_in_ckpt=None):
  return _MonkeyEmbeddingColumn(sparse_id_column, dimension, combiner, initializer, ckpt_to_load_from, tensor_name_in_ckpt)
```

Then find the calls like this:

```
tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(workclass, dimension=8)
```

and replace "tf.contrib.layers." with "monkey_" so you now have:

```
  deep_columns = [
      monkey_embedding_column(workclass, dimension=8),
      monkey_embedding_column(education, dimension=8),
      monkey_embedding_column(marital_status,
                                         dimension=8),
      monkey_embedding_column(gender, dimension=8),
      monkey_embedding_column(relationship, dimension=8),
      monkey_embedding_column(race, dimension=8),
      monkey_embedding_column(native_country,
                                         dimension=8),
      monkey_embedding_column(occupation, dimension=8),
      age,
      education_num,
      capital_gain,
      capital_loss,
      hours_per_week,
  ]
```

So now it uses the MonkeyEmbeddingColumn class with the modified key property (works like all the other key properties from feature_column.py).  This lets the code run to completion, but I'm not 100% sure it's correct as it reports the accuracy as:

```
accuracy: 0.818316
```

As this is slightly worse than the wide-only training, I wonder if it has this accuracy in Python 2 or if my fix is lowering the accuracy by causing a training problem.

**Update** I installed in Python 2 and the wide_n_deep gets over 0.85 accuracy, so this "fix" lets the code run but seems to be doing the wrong thing.  I'll debug and see what Python 2 gets for these values and see if it can be fixed properly in Python 3.  I'm curious too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Jesse suggested use the master (no branch on git clone) when you are downloading the tutorial source code from tensorflow website.
Second, you only need to pass the first two parameters to the class. You will get some warnings on the way; just ignore them and wait for the program to finish.
So use the following code on top of the tutorial source code: or download the 
modified code from here: [Modified Version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/henaras/tensorflow/66bebf4c03e15686f91c692be6efee671107bf32/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py)

```
from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers.feature_column import _EmbeddingColumn

class _MonkeyEmbeddingColumn(_EmbeddingColumn):
  # override the key property
  @property
  def key(self):
    return "{}".format(self)

def monkey_embedding_column(sparse_id_column,
                     dimension,
                     combiner="mean",
                     initializer=None,
                     ckpt_to_load_from=None,
                     tensor_name_in_ckpt=None):
  return _MonkeyEmbeddingColumn(sparse_id_column, dimension)
```